# How to install Kiln/Mercurial on GoDaddy shared hosting account?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, kiln

I am currently using [Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/), a Mercurial derivative, for version control, and trying to figure out the best way to implement this for my application on a GoDaddy shared hosting account?

Currently, I am manually pushing changes through FTP.  Is there a better way to do this?  For example, can I create a hook that automatically uploads the changed files to FTP when I push to the repository?  Is it possible to install Kiln on our actual server GoDaddy server to push and pull code from?

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kiln is basically just Mercurial with a few extensions, so you can run any repository server on your own hosted website if it allows you to run Python (looks like GoDaddy does). A plain [hgweb Mercurial server](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#hgweb) will do. See the website for setup instructions, I think that’s beyond the scope of this answer :).

Once you have set up this server, you can set up a hook in the Mercurial server to export the repository to your `httpdocs` directory whenever it’s pushed:

```
[hooks]
changegroup.archive = hg archive -r tip path/to/httpdocs
```

Alternatively you can actually configure hgweb to put the repository inside your httpdocs directory and configure the hook to update on every push. Advantages are that it will be a little faster and also cleans up removed files:

```
[hooks]
changegroup.update = hg update
```

A **WARNING** though: if you take this approach you need to make sure to set up your web server to ignore the `.hg` folder, otherwise anyone will be able to access your repository. Example Apache configuration:

```
<Directory /path/to/httpdocs/.hg/>
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```